# asp.net: send an object's event from a UserControl to its Parent

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I have a **User** class with functions to **Login()** and **Logout()** and **GetData()**. There's a ***UserChanged*** event, it fires when either of these functions are called.

I have UserControls on my Default.aspx (they're added dynamically).

I have a UserControl named Login.ascx. It provides the functionality to use the User class: you can Login / Logout here. I have an ****EventHandler* for **UserChanged***** (if I don't have one, it will fail with a object not found exception).

I need to alert the other UserControls about the changes to the user's state. 
I somehow need to pass the UserChanged event from Login.ascx to its Parent, Default.aspx.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Login.ascx.cs**

```
public delegate void OnUserChangedHandler(object sender);
public OnUserChangedHandler OnUserChanged;

private void RaiseUserChangedEvent() //Call this method when the user changes
{
    //UserChanged Event
    if (OnUserChanged != null)
    {
        OnUserChanged(this);
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    loginControl.OnUserChanged += OnUserChanged;
}

private void OnUserChanged(object sender)
{
    //Code here to do something with other controls on this page
}
```

Comment: Thats how I tried to do it. The problem is that the "OnUserChanged" event object is null, so it is never fired... I know for sure that the listener is added (I break and see it happen) but when it needs to be fired it is null...

Comment: @Ted did you ever find a way to make this work?

Comment: Oh, 12 years ago. I can hardly remember what it was about. So, I would guess a "no" on that one. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option to tell parent controls about some actions - RaiseBubbleEvent.

You can read about it here: [Using RaiseBubbleEvent to Tell a Parent ASP.NET Control to Rebind](http://trevsdev.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-raisebubbleevent-to-tell-parent.html)

The thing is that child controls calls Method **RaiseBubbleEvent**(...)
And **all** it's parents (no matter how far are they in hierarchy) can override method **OnBubbleEvent** to handle this event.
return value of that methods indicates whether it's needed to pass this event to the next parent or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, the control needs to broadcast the UserChanged Event, and then page needs to be wired up to listen for the event.

There are a lot a good resources out there on how to implement custom events and event handlers...

Try this one from csharphelp.com

http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive603.html

Comment: So I need to create a delegate for the UserChange event?

Comment: Look at Jon's Post, he has some great code snippets... I think he is showing what I was suggesting. GL