# Firing events in UserControls (ASP.NET) - the event object is null?

Tags: asp.net, events, viewstate

I have a problem with the Event object being null when I want to fire the event. There are other threads here and on the net about this:

- [asp.net: send an object's event from a UserControl to its Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039440/asp-net-send-an-objects-event-from-a-usercontrol-to-its-parent)
- http://objectmix.com/csharp/120067-event-object-null-when-event-fired-webusercontrol-asp-net-ajax.html

However, I have tried according to what is recommended in those post, but the event object is null. Here is the code:

In my Page who is to listen to the Event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
          fieldCustomer1.CustomerSelected += new UserControls.Field_Customer.uintDelegate(fieldCustomer1_CustomerSelected);
     }
}
```

The Page_Load above is executed well before the EVent is fired (below).

The code in the UserControl containing the Event:

```
public partial class Field_Customer : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
        public delegate void uintDelegate(uint id);
        public event uintDelegate CustomerSelected;

        // ... yada yada yada code code code

        [DirectMethod]  // ext.net stuff
        public void FireCustomerSelected()
        {
            if (CustomerSelected != null) // the CustomerSelected is always null
                CustomerSelected(_CustomerId);
        }
}
```

Is it ViewState or something like that, that I am missing? Why is CustomerSelected always null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your eventhandler should be subscribed in every page load and not just the !postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

          fieldCustomer1.CustomerSelected += new UserControls.Field_Customer.uintDelegate(fieldCustomer1_CustomerSelected);

}
```